# MongoDB Find() issue

Tags: mongodb

I couldn't fetch the following result from MongoDB using following query.

**Query**

```
db.usersessiondet.find({"session":{"lastAccess":1330059784}});
```

Sample Storage Data in MongoDB.

```
{ "Id" : "Id9017", "_id" : "Id9017", "expires" : 1330059785, "session" : "{\"lastAccess\":1330059784,\"cookie\":{\"originalMaxAge\":14400000,\"expires\":\"2013-01-20T21:57:07.659Z\",\"httpOnly\":true,\"path\":\"/\"},\"messages\":{\"comCt\":{\"timedifference\":0,\"comCt_bytime\":0,\"commet_user_Id1574\":[{\"id\":\"Id9017_1330059784685\",\"from\":\"Id9017\",\"message\":\"asdf\",\"self\":0,\"old\":1,\"sent\":1330059784}]}}}" }
```

I tried

> db.sample.find();
>   { "_id" : "Id9017", "Id" : "Id9017", "expires" : 1330059785, "session" : "{\"lastAccess\":1330059784,\"cookie\":{\"originalMaxAge\":14400000,\"expires\":\"2013-01-20T21:57:07.659Z\",\"httpOnly\":true,\"path\":\"/\"},\"messages\":{\"comCt\":{\"timedifference\":0,\"comCt_bytime\":0,\"commet_user_Id1574\":[{\"id\":\"Id9017_1330059784685\",\"from\":\"Id9017\",\"message\":\"asdf\",\"self\":0,\"old\":1,\"sent\":1330059784}]}}}" }
>
> db.sample.find({"session.lastAccess":1330059784}});

no result return.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have stored a JSON encoded **string** in MongoDB:

```
{
    "Id" : "Id9017", 
    "_id" : "Id9017", 
    "expires" : 1330059785, 
    "session" : "{\"lastAccess\":1330059784,\"cookie\":{\"origina…
```

A JSON encoded string can not simply be queried like this as MongoDB's query language is not designed to go into strings for queries. You do need to store it as actual field names/values, such as:

```
{
    "Id" : "Id9017", 
    "_id" : "Id9017", 
    "expires" : 1330059785, 
    "session" : {
        "lastAccess": 1330059784,
        "cookie" : { "origina…
```

If you store your data properly like that, your query will work.

Answer (score -1):

Dot notation instead: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/glossary/#term-dot-notation

```
db.usersessiondet.find({"session.lastAccess":1330059784}});
```

Comment: No Its not working. Already i tried.db.usersessiondet.find({"session.lastAccess":1330059784}}); Its return empty set.

Comment: > db.sample.find();
{ "_id" : "Id9017", "Id" : "Id9017", "expires" : 1330059785, "session" : "{\"lastAccess\":1330059784,\"cookie\":{\"originalMaxAge\":14400000,\"expires\":\"2013-01-20T21:57:07.659Z\",\"httpOnly\":true,\"path\":\"/\"},\"messages\":{\"comCt\":{\"timedifference\":0,\"comCt_bytime\":0,\"commet_user_Id1574\":[{\"id\":\"Id9017_1330059784685\",\"from\":\"Id9017\",\"message\":\"asdf\",\"self\":0,\"old\":1,\"sent\":1330059784}]}}}" }
>
>
> db.sample.find({"session.lastAccess":1330059784});
>

Comment: A downvote for misreading the pre-pended speech mark? Some people really need to undrstand what a mistake is...